# Update specific values in more than one column - SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, sql-update

I have a table that contains two columns, both have email values.
I want to create a query that update a specific data in both columns.

For example if I have two records of the email `'a@aa.aa'` in one column and three records of `'a@aa.aa'` in the other column I want them both to be updated.
Here for example I want that all the `'g@gg.ggg'` will be `'a@aa.aa'`:

[image]

My question is how the query should look like.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Write 2 separate updates.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to run two update statements:

```
update table
    set col1 = <newval>
    where col1 = <oldval>;

update table
    set col2 = <newval>
    where col2 = <oldval>;
```

This begs of the question of why *two* columns are storing the same data.  Perhaps you need to review your data structure and use a junction table for this information.

Comment: The table is for friend requests and my user key is the email, is that wrong?

Comment: @Tal apparently yes, every user should have a unique ID and that should be stored in the friend request table, in another table that id is associated with an email. You should not use mutable data as key / identifier for rows... because exactly your scenario happens, you *just* want to change the email and have to update it in 100s of places - not good.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist of one statement:

```
update table
     set col1 = iif(col1 = 'aa', 'bb', col1),
         col2 = iif(col2 = 'aa', 'bb', col2)
where col1 = 'aa' or col2 = 'aa'
```